450-ohm ladder line fact vs fiction
I am considering many possible doublet antenna scenarios for a multi-band antenna (80 meters to hopefully, 6 meters) customized to my specific home situation.
Everything is a compromise. I will be using a 450-ohm windowed ladder cable in several scenarios, but I keep running into a lack of clear facts surrounding using a 450-ohm ladder line.  For example, a repeated "consensus" is that the cable should be away from the ground by several widths of the window, not on the ground or buried, it shouldn't ever be close to other metal structures, and that it easily 'radiates.'  Unfortunately, several Elmer's out there claim much of that so-called "conventional wisdom" is a bit overblown and overstated.
Can anyone direct me to some legitimate research (a bit less anecdotal) that has been done on the 450-ohm ladder line?  I don't mind conventional wisdom, but I can tell that much of it is just "parroted" from someone else they heard from or some YouTuber rather than based on genuine hands-on experience.
Anyways, I would love to read some facts if anyone out there can direct me. I don't mind experimenting, but I'd prefer not to start from scratch if I don't have to.  Thanks in advance!

Not that it matters, but I'm guessing that this is actually 420 Ω line.

The more that the conductor diameter is increased, the lower the loss. In free space, almost all of the loss in transmission lines are I²R losses in the copper wires.

@Dereck What lie?


a repeated "consensus" is that the cable should be ... not on the ground or buried

This is an accurate statement. Laying the cable on the ground, and especially burying it, is bad.

The earth is lossy and partially conductive.

The earth will greatly affect the impedance of the line.


That's why nobody buries ladder line. If you need to bury a feedline, use flooded coaxial cable.

You shouldn't even put ladder line in a buried plastic pipe. The EM field surrounding it is likely larger than a reasonable size pipe, even if you centrally support it inside the pipe.
This comes from almost 50 years experience as a ham, and reading relevant info from many technical gurus smarter than I am. Sorry if it seems anecdotal. :-)

Excellent points. Ladder line characteristic impedance is 'more sensitive' and more easily disrupted compared with a "closed coax".  This makes so much more sense.  I'm going to run some empirical tests on long ladder lines. I suspect these kinds of tests have been run in the past - I just can't find them).  Thanks for making these points!

Here's some theory as to why this matters...keep this in mind and decide for yourself when you should worry.
All transmission line (coax too, not just ladder line) works by forming opposing magnetic fields between the two conductors.  In all transmission lines, this works best when the two fields are equal and opposite and thus cancel, preventing signal from leaking out of the line.  (With coax, it's still possible to mess this up, but it's much harder.)
With ladder line, surrounding conductive objects, including parallel metal and conductive earth, the fields in the ladder line can interact asymmetrically with the external objects and imbalance the line if the external conductor is too close.  (How much this matters with the ground depends on how conductive it is.)
This can be somewhat mitigated by twisting the ladder line, so that the intruding effect is now symmetrical, affecting both wires in the transmission line somewhat equally.  The right density of twists can effectively reduce the distance conductive objects must be separated from the ladder line.
It's not metal objects that matter, but long parallel metal objects.
It's not mere ground that matters, but conductive ground.
The degree to which an object has a long segment parallel to the ladder line and how conductive it is to RF fields affects how much this matters and how well the twists in the ladder line will mitigate it.

Thanks for your accurate reply. To advance this further, assume the only variable in question is whether the balanced feed can be on (or in) the ground. Assume a vertical antenna (80m-10m), where the ground is vital to the antenna circuit. Per theory, we are primarily concerned with ground signals that might create an "unbalance" in the two wires of the feedline. It seems logical that long wavelength signals won't "imbalance" the lines, given the rail-rail distance of the window feed is only an inch or so.  Under this situation, am I missing another reason not to bury the balanced feedline?

The other answer has a very good point.  The windowed ladder line has windows for a reason.  Removal of that small amount of plastic tweaks the impedance.  So now you put a bunch of dirt that is more conductive than the plastic near the ladder line and it's going to totally throw off the impedance.  It doesn't matter how balanced it is if the impedance is wrong.

Note that a few bumps on the ground isn't going to mess up the ladder line... it's when you change the dielectric constant of the material near the line for a significant distance that it matters.  Burrying it is about the worst thing you could do short of wrapping it tightly around a steel pipe.

Ahhhh... very nice!! This makes sense to me. We are saying that the ladder line is more sensitive to environments because it is too easy to modify the effective characteristic impedance of that line. Long swaths of nearby conductors, "Earth," and moisture easily fall into that category. Putting the ladder line in larger PVC (if buried) might be 'better' if there were no leaks into the PVC. But, that seems unrealistic in the long term. So - armed with this - my next plan is to confirm all this by running characteristic impedance tests on ladder lines to measure this impact. THX!

The PVC itself will change the impedance of the ladder line.   It's just not a good fit to burry it.  Use the right tool for the right job..   You could suspend it in the center of, say, a 2ft diameter pipe.  Or I know, you could use a metal pipe instead of a pvc pipe, and suspend a single conductor in the center of it.     Or you could just buy some coax.

That's good to know, "user10489." I'm going to make some empirical measurements over the weekend. I'll use my Rig Expert (AA230) with a long piece of 450-ohm ladder line in and out of PVC. It's not that I doubt the PVC will have some impact on the characteristic impedance, I'm sure it must - but given that PVC has particular characteristics of its own - I'm really curious to quantify that impact.   This was a good discussion (for me)—thanks for all your input!

Also - just to clarify -  I realize burying coax is a natural (normal) way to do the feedline. But...if I'm using a doublet  - with a fairly long distance to cover -  I thought a 100ft 450-ohm ladder line would be cheaper than a remote antenna tuner. So- I was exploring alternatives. Hence the original exploratory question.

I was thinking similar things for different reasons and it turns out ladder line can be more expensive than coax.

@Michael with coax, the field is almost entirely in the space between the inner and outer conductors; what's outside the shield is inconsequential. With any sort of twinlead/ladder line, the field is in the space between and around the two conductors, and any conductive or dielectric material in that space matters. Both because it messes with the impedance and because if it's closer to one conductor than the other it causes an imbalance which makes the feedline want to radiate/receive rather than be a transmission line.
